# jQuery fade out then fade in

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

There's a bunch on this topic, but I havn't found an instance that applies well to my situation.

Fade a picture out and then fade another picture in. Instead, I'm running into an issue where the first fades out and immediately (before the animation is finished) the next fades in.

I read about this once and can't remember exactly what the trick was..

http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/gBw9j/

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 84, accepted):

fade the other in in the callback of fadeout, which runs when fadeout is done.  Using your code:

```
$('#two, #three').hide();
$('.slide').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.fadeOut(function(){ $this.next().fadeIn(); });
});
```

alternatively, you can just "pause" the chain, but you need to specify for how long:

```
$(this).fadeOut().next().delay(500).fadeIn();
```

Comment: Ah, that's right. Thanks for the reminder. now that fadeOut has a function attached, where can I adjust it's speed? fadeIn's easy :)

Comment: `fadeOut('fast', function(){ ... })` or `fadeOut(200, function(){ ... })`

Answer (score 5):

After jQuery 1.6, using promise seems like a better option.

```
var $div1 = $('#div1');
var fadeOutDone = $div1.fadeOut().promise();
// do your logic here, e.g.fetch your 2nd image url
$.get('secondimageinfo.json').done(function(data){
  fadeoOutDone.then(function(){
    $div1.html('<img src="' + data.secondImgUrl + '" alt="'data.secondImgAlt'">');
    $div1.fadeIn();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This might help: http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/gBw9j/
Basically `$(this).fadeOut().next().fadeIn();` is what you require

Comment: Here is few more collection of fadein fadeout example http://webdevlopementhelp.blogspot.in/2009/09/jquery-fade-in-fade-out-effect.html

Answer (score 0):

With async functions and promises, it now can work as simply as this:

```
async function foobar() {
  await $("#example").fadeOut().promise();
  doSomethingElse();
  await $("#example").fadeIn().promise();
}
```